# Grafana Text Panels - Remove White Bar?

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana 7.5.6. When I insert a text panel (sometimes with words, sometimes a blank one to alter spacing), a white outline bar appears at the bottom and sometimes to the right of the box. (Sorry stackoverflow won't let me include a picture)

Has anyone else experienced this/have a fix? Thanks!

Comment: Those are Grafana CSS issues. It's a good idea to upgrade to the latest Grafana, where they may be fixed. Or switch to light UI theme, where it is not visible (work around, not a solution).

Answer (score 0):

If spacing between panels is your requirement, then you can also try this plugin called [Separator panel for Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/mxswat-separator-panel/).